# Increasing conditions in WHERE clause will increas the search speed?

Tags: mysql, performance, search

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  |   code  |
+----+-------+---------+
| 1  | jack  | 1       |
| 2  | acton | 1       |
| 3  | aiken | 1       |
| 4  | peter | null    |
| 5  | ash   | null    |
| 6  | fabia | 2       |
| 7  | ubon  | null    |
| 8  | taavi | null    |
| 9  | wade  | 2       |
| 10 | ian   | 1       |
+----+-------+---------+
```

I want to select the row which its `id` is 4. And here is my query:

```
select * from mytable where id = 4
```

Also I know `code` value of that row is `null`. Now I want to know, if I add this `... and code = null` will increase the speed of searching?

Comment: Your proposed change will return zero rows. Use `is null`. What indexes are on the table? Assuming a unique index on id this extra check will likely slow things down slightly.

Comment: @Shafizadeh if id is unique and code is indexed, adding "... and code is null" won't make any difference, only the id index will be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add:

```
and code = null
```

then you will not get any rows returned, because `= null` always returns `null`.  And `where` filters out rows where the value is not true.

Instead, you wnat:

```
and code is null
```

Presumably, `id` has an index on it (all primary keys have an index).  If so, the SQL engine will probably do one more comparison after it has fetched the row to ensure that `code` matches the condition.  Given all the other work for fetching the data, this is very, very negligible.  Including the additional condition would in all likelihood have no discernible effect on performance.